# Antd table, how to sort by date including the whole timestamp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have this item

```js
const data: Item[] = [
    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'John Brown',
        date: moment('10-10-2019').format('L'),
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        name: 'Joe Black',
        date: moment('11-10-2019').format('L'),
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        name: 'Jim Green',
        date: moment('7-10-2019').format('L'),
        address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: 4,
        name: 'Jim Red',
        date: moment('8-10-2019 8:00 PM').format('L'),
        // date: moment('8-10-2019 8:00 PM').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
        address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    },
];
```

If I use that data for "date" , and I use the following sorter it works fine

```js
sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.date).unix() - moment(b.date).unix()
```

But I want the data to be a bit more complex, like this

```js
date: moment('8-10-2019 8:00 PM').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

Which evaluates to `August 10th 2019, 8:00:00 pm`

Problem is, that I can't sort that data with the above sorter.
How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sorter:

```
sorter: (a, b) =>
    new Date(moment(a.date, "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").format("LLL")) -
    new Date(moment(b.date, "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").format("LLL")),
```

[image: Edit]

Also take note that there's a deprecate warning that you are using a value (your provided date) that is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. You can check a valid format on `moment` documentation.